# Why threads are not working?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my following code:

```
private int counter = 0;

public void incC() {
    counter++;
    System.out.println("Counter is: "+counter +  "  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

public void printC() {
    System.out.println("Counter  is: "+counter +  "  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
       Stuff stuff = new Stuff();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
           stuff.incC();
       });

       Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
           stuff.printC();
       });

       t1.start();
       t2.start();

       t1.join();
       t2.join();
  }
}
```

Here's my output:

```
Counter  is: 1  Thread-1
Counter is: 1  Thread-0
```

- Here `t1.join()` is called first. So shouldn't thread `t2` should wait for thread `t1` to die?
- How's it possible for thread `t2` to output first before `t1`?

Comment: No, `join()` makes the current thread (the 'main'-thread in this case) wait until `t1` and `t2` are finished. In other words: the threads are working fine.

Comment: If you want to wait for `t1`'s termination and then start `t2`, you have to call `t2.start()` after `t1.join()`....

Comment: what's the problem? the threads are probably working, you need to sync access to `counter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t1.join()` makes the *current* thread wait for thread `t1` to die. It has no effects on the timing of any other thread but the current one. You have started two threads and they will run concurrently with no ordering constraints.

I should also note that starting two threads only to have one wait for the other's death defeats the purpose of multithreading.

Comment: I find that these newbies often misunderstand what "current thread" means.  First of all, which thread is "current" when you've got eight CPUs all cranking away?  Then, couple that with the fact that noobs often don't realize that the main thread is a thread.  They come up with ideas like,  the current thread is the thread that "I" just created and started.  I like to explain `join()` by saying something like, "`t1.join()` doesn't do anything to `t1`; It just waits for `t1` to die."

Answer (score 0):

1. `join()` forces to wait current (in your case the main) thread to death of `t1`, so `t2` continues to work
2. Order for thread execution is not fixed because they work in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Both threads works in parallel and therefore no guarantee on which thread will finish first in your case.

If you want a specific thread to finish first you have to start it and join it with your main thread then start and join the second thread like follows.

```
    t1.start();
    t1.join();

    t2.start();
    t2.join();
```

Set names for the threads for better understanding.

Also change your question because your threads are working fine.